# Access servlet without login openfire

Tags: android, plugins, openfire

I implemented a Opefire plugin.All is working but i want to use my servlet without login just like we can access PresentStatusServelt (Which is in presence plugin by `"http://localhost:9090/plugins/presence/status"`) without login.

my **init()** method code of servlet is:

```
@Override

        public void init(ServletConfig servletConfig) throws ServletException {

            super.init(servletConfig);

           // Exclude this servlet from requiring the user to login

        AuthCheckFilter.addExclude("myplugin/upload");

    }
```

so   why `AuthCheckFilter.addExclude("myplugin/upload");`  this method is not working for me. When i directly hit my servlet without login ,I am always redirected for login page then after login I come to my desired page..But I want to access my servlet withot login..Am I missing something..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you overrided the `destroy()` method? By doing so you will be able to access your servlet without login.

```
@Override
public void destroy() {
        super.destroy();
           // Release the excluded URL
        AuthCheckFilter.removeExclude("presence/status");
    }
```